# How can I get a users that exceed $ 1000 in the last 30 days? for each user last 30 days. SQL Having Limit

Tags: mysql, sql

i have table products in DB.
Products: id, user_id, product_price.
How can I get a users that exceed $ 1000 in the last 30 days? (**for each user last 30 days**)
My script not help me:

```
SELECT   t.user_id,
        ,SUM(t.product_price) 
FROM ( SELECT p.user_id
            , p.product_price 
        FROM products p 
        ORDER BY p.id DESC LIMIT 30 
     ) t 
GROUP BY t.user_id 
HAVING SUM(t.product_price) >= 1000
```

Comment: If there is no date field, then how will you determine records of last 30 days?

Comment: Hint: WHERE-condition based on date vs. current_date - 30 days

Comment: LIMIT 30 can show the first 30 rows. You need to use something like that : "WHERE <your date>  between DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE , INTERVAL -30 DAY) and CURRENT_DATE"

Comment: @dnoeth yea, you are right, i forgot to add date,I thought it was a date (in my mind) thank you guys

Comment: What do you mean by “each user”? Do you mean last 30 day with activity (not last 30 calendar days.?)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a subquery, you need a `WHERE`.  "Last 30 days" implies a time period up to today.  For that, use `curdate()` (or a similar construct):

```
SELECT p.user_id, SUM(p.product_price)
FROM products p 
WHERE p.<date column> >= curdate() - interval 30 day
GROUP BY p.user_id
HAVING SUM(p.product_price) >= 1000;
```

Presumably, you don't have future dates in the data, so you don't need to check that the date is in the past.

The names of tables in your database are quite suspicious.  I don't see why a `user_id` would be in a table called `products`.

Comment: i set a user_id in table products, that i want to know wich user exceed 1000$